# How to display a card with 90th percentile in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am new to PowerBI, and am trying to use a card to display three statistics: average, medium and 90th percentile. I understand how to create a card for average, and a card for medium.

How do I create a card for 90th percentile? There is no build in function 90th percentile. I can only see sum, average, minimum, maximum, count(distinct), count, standard deviation, variance, and median option.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a measure, and not use the built in aggregation functions of Power BI visuals. You can use the [PERCENTILE.INC](https://dax.guide/percentile-inc/) function, that will find the percentile over a column. Your measure will be:

```
Percentile of whatever = PERCENTILE.INC('tablename'[columnname], 0.9)
```

You should not use columns and then use visual aggregation type in Power BI, these are called 'naked measures' it is always best to create a measure, as you can reuse them in other visuals and the Power BI engine will calculate a bit quicker.

Comment: Percentile should be in [0,1], so use `0.9` not `90`.